# WCF binary security token before signature

Tags: wcf, ssl, soap-client

I was given a WSDL to access a SOAP 1.1 web service.  The WSDL only references a binary security token one time.  The request that they are expecting requires a second binary security token before the signature tag but after the encrypt key tag.  I need to somehow tell WCF to add this additional security token tag that is not present in the WSDL schema.  The strange thing that I noticed relevant to my pursuit of solving this problem is that SOAPUI is adding the token even though it is not present in the WSDL schema. The following information is relevant in understanding the problem:

This is the config file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>  
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="customWebRealmBinding">
          <security messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" defaultAlgorithmSuite="TripleDesRsa15"     
                    authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampLast"
                    includeTimestamp="true"
                    allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" requireDerivedKeys="false" />
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004"></textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" realm="weblogic" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                          requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://XXX/XXX/XXX/XXXService?WSDL"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customWebRealmBinding"
        contract="XXXService.XXXServiceType" name="XXXerviceTypeSoapPort" behaviorConfiguration="XXXBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="XXXXXXX"/>
        <certificateReference findValue="XXXXX, XXXXXX, XXX, XXX XXX. XXXX, XXXX" 
          storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName"/>
      </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="XXXBehavior">
          <callbackDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" 
                              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName"
                              findValue="XXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" 
                                  x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" 
                                  findValue="XXXX, XXXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX. XXXXX, XXXXX" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="NLog.LogReceiverService.LogReceiverOneWayForwardingService">
        <endpoint address="https://XXXXService?WSDL" 
         name="XXXServiceEndpoint" binding="customBinding" contract="XXXService.XXXServiceType"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://XXX/XXX/XXXService?WSDL"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1048576" tracemode="protocolonly">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
          <add name="MyConsole"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add
        name="MyTraceFile"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" />
      <add name="MyConsole" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
    </sharedListeners>

    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>

  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

This is the WCF message that is created when I do it:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3"/>
    <a:MessageID u:Id="_4">urn:uuid:</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo u:Id="_5">
      <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_6">https:XXXXXXXXX?WSDL</a:To>
    <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-XXXX">
        <u:Created>2018-08-28T13:32:45.912Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2018-08-28T13:37:45.912Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-4fcc794b-4898-4bd2-b842-1bb0b98b800d-3" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-
        open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">TOKEN NUMBERS=</o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="_0">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-
                             1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">agOMixYQcvcrttth/vzpcgfGaRg=</o:KeyIdentifier>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>CYPHER NUMBERS AND LETTERS</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
        <e:ReferenceList>
          <e:DataReference URI="#_2"/>
        </e:ReferenceList>
      </e:EncryptedKey>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#_1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>VALUES</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#_3">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>VALUES</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#_4">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>VALUES</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#_5">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>VALUES</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#_6">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>A/VzEXRgimkP4p4nf6geYy68axI=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#uuid-XXXXXXX">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference URI="#uuid-XXXXXXXXXXX"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_1">
    <e:EncryptedData xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="_2" 
                     Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
      <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
      <e:CipherData>
        <e:CipherValue>XXXXXXXXXXX</e:CipherValue>
      </e:CipherData>
    </e:EncryptedData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want it to look just like the one above but I want another binary security token between the end EncryptedKey tag and before the beginning of the signature tag. Programmatically I am really just setting the username, password and cert values and calling the service.

Any help would be great!  Thanks!